# Checkbox list keep disabled

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

Trying to use checkbox lists in (calendar booking system). The checkbox should be disabled and red if there are any data in the database against the date and hour. This all work perfectly here is the code. Using vb.net

OK i found a way how to clear the checkboxes

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim chboxItem As ListItem
    For Each chboxItem In CheckBoxListMon.Items
        i += 1
        If (i Mod 1 = 0) Then
            chboxItem.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next



Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

    Try
        strQuery = "SELECT BookingDate, checkBoxItem, BookRegUserID,Booked FROM bookings INNER JOIN checkboxitems where checkBoxItem = BookingTime"

        MySQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

        dbCon.Open()

        DR = MySQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While DR.Read

            bookDate = DR.Item("BookingDate")
            bookTime = DR.Item("checkBoxItem")
            bookRegID = DR.Item("BookRegUserID")
            booked = DR.Item("Booked")

            Dim test As String = bookTime.ToString()

            Select Case True

                Case bookDate = lblMonday.Text And CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(test) IsNot Nothing

                    CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Enabled = False
                    CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Attributes.Add("Style", "color: red;")

            End Select
        End While
        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

When the page load it would not change the ones from the database. But when i reload the page it will actually work perfect.

Where can i put the check just to be sure that they are already in the memory.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks all.

Petr

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the data when another week is selected because you are using the same controls for each week. You should be able to do this in whatever control you are using to toggle through the weeks.

Page_LoadComplete can only be expedted to fire each time a page has completed loading, that is why your controls work when going to another page and back.